# Digital Portfolio CMS Identification - Yellow/Black, Teutonic

Tags: cms, graphic-design

A bit of a goose chase, a bit of a silly question.

Recently I was researching content management/templates for digital design portfolios, and came across a killer bit of software. Unfortunately, I forgot to bookmark and have lost all trace of it. Even after thorough googling and history sifting, no dice.

In terms of identifiable properties, the product had a yellow and black color scheme, very clean and minimal web presence, and a teutonic coat-of-arms style mark. The price point was somewhere around $89; the name may have started with an S.

Can anyone identify this mysterious piece of software?

Comment: Not sure this is on-topic given you're looking for a template, not a CMS.

Comment: Did you check your Google Web History? http://www.google.com/history

Comment: Asking for identification of a specific software [is off-topic](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/818/60). You could make this question on-topic by stating which features the CMS needs to have. Then answers could recommend any suitable solution, not necessarily/only the one you have in mind.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [Semplice](http://semplicelabs.com), which is a portfolio CMS based on Wordpress.

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you so much. I'd given up hope, haha.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Your answer was downvoted for two reasons: First its on an off-topic question which is something many people frown upon, even though you as a new user couldn't know. Second its too short. We want our answers to be full fledged personal recommendations that point out the pros and cons of a software. Just a link and "This could do" is not enough. Have a look at [the faq](meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) on our meta site to get an impression what goes and how it should look like. Hope to see you around.